# Is there a way to pass a variable from PowerShell to the R environment?

Tags: r, powershell

Assume I have a PowerShell command that runs a R script:

```
& "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\Rscript.exe" C:\Users\UserName\DocumentsMyScript.R
```

Is there a way in this command that I can define a variable in the R environment so that it can be used in my R script?

Comment: R function `commandArgs` might be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `--args` option followed by the argument(s) you want to pass. For example, if you want to pass a variable named "myvar" with a value of "stackoverflow" to your R script, you can modify the PowerShell to this:

`& "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\Rscript.exe" C:\Users\UserName\DocumentsMyScript.R --args myvar="stackoverflow"`

In R you can then access the value of "myvar" with `commandArgs()`

```
myvar <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)['myvar']
```

Comment: I have tried using the `--args` option just like you write with a R script `myvar <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)['myvar']
writeLines(myvar, "C:/Users/UserName/test.txt")` however I am getting a text file with NA written in it, as if it is not parsing the value of the argument.

Comment: Put `print(commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE))` as the first line of your script and you'll see what you get.  I don't think R will do any parsing, so I'd expect `"myvar=stackoverflow"` (though the quotes might be different).

Comment: @user2554330 I get the vector `"--args"        "myvar=stackoverflow"`, so I assume I just have to pass the arguments as `--args stackoverflow` in PowerShell and then `myvar <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)[1]` in my R script. There's no way to actually define the values in PowerShell? I have to define `myvar` in the script itself, is that correct?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question.  The command you give will set `myvar` to `"--args"`, not to `"stackoverflow"`.  You should use the second entry and process it to extract the value.  A different alternative is to use environment variables, but I don't use Powershell, so I don't know how you would set those.